# iPad2 Nav disappears behind jquery Flexslider slideshow?

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slideshow, meta

Hi I'm using a wordpress plugin called metaslider which used jquery 'flexslider' slideshow effect.

It looks really nice unfortunately on an ipad the fade option makes the navigation dropdown go behind the slideshow. Bizarre ey! I've tried z-index but this doesn't work. 
http://brightmist.co.uk/simplicity/themes/flourish/?themedemo=Flourish

Anyone else ever had this unusual issue?

Thanks Judi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome fixed it so simple

```
.flexslider { margin: 0 !important; z-index:0 !important;}
#nav ul {z-index: 9999;}
```